# Retrieving data extension used to filter e-mail send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk

I'm new to ExactTarget, and I'm having some hard time to do something that should be simple.

We direct our e-mails using a list of All Subscribers, and filter then using data extensions. When I go on the tracking page of a particular e-mail, there it is in the Summary, all the info and the Data Extensions, on the format:

name (number) sent 
(Using All Subscribers) (number sent)

[image: Screenshot of the Tracking Summary]

The thing is, when I do a tracking extract I don't get this information. I tried to extract everything that was possible, and couldn't get this information. All I get is, for each sendID (for each subscriber in fact), the ListID, which will always be the same (the one for All Subscribers). I want to know which segment we used.

Tried to deep dive on the SOAP API, with no luck, again all I can retrieve is the List, never the data extension.

This must be retrievable, once it is on the Tracking Summary. So my question is how do I retrieve is.

I considered programming a simple robot to scrape for this info, but there must be a better way.

Thanks

EDIT: Clarification. What I want to do is to discover what is the Data Extension used for each Job ID (SendID). Don't need to know what is on the Data Extension, just the name of it is enough. I obviously don't want to open each tracking summary to find out, and I am reluctant to create a scraping robot for this purpose. The information is obviously stored in a linked way to the Job ID (otherwise the information wouldn't be available at all), so what I'm asking for is how to get this link

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the intereactions tab
2. Create a Data Extract Activity for your data extension.
3. Create a File Transfer activity to move the file out of the holding tank to where you can get it.
4. Automate it using a program or automation studio if you like.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:  OK, here is what I have done, based on your edits.  Create a DE to store this info.  Then, at the top of all your emails put this block.  You could put this in a content area and just call that at the top of each email.  This will do an insert at send time.

```
%%[
  SET @jobid = jobid
  SET @source = _DataSourceName
  InsertDE("data_ext_name", "colNameForJobid", @jobid, "colNameForSource", @source)
]%%
```

Run your reports against that new DE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I asked. Will try to clarify on the post

Comment: Thanks again, guess that would work for the e-mails I'll send in the future. But what about all my history of e-mails? Anyway to target that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so.  The info is certainly still within ET, but may not be publicly accessible.  If you need it, you may need a short engagement with our services team for them to do the data mining for you.  Someone with more knowledge than I may need to chime in here.

Comment: Thanks again, Timothy. Sorry about my honesty, but it's really stupid to store information, display it on a tracking report, but then make it not retrievable through API nor by its own tracking extract tool

Comment: @Inox did you manage to find a solution?