# How Do I Retrieve the DataExtension Used for A Send (via the SOAP API)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

Similar to this question: [Retrieving data extension used to filter e-mail send](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42043/retrieving-data-extension-used-to-filter-e-mail-send/42047#42047)

I want to be able to figure out which data extension was used for a send, but I want to do so via the SOAP API.

Comment: Is this for future sends?  Or does this include past sends?

Comment: It includes past sends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point, you don't have access to that info without a custom services engagement.  For future sends, it's not too late; you can use sendlogging to store this information.

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually misunderstood. Going forward, how do I use sendlogging to achieve this?

Comment: I guess this is good enough: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/5/10/